# zypper install rpm and see commands that are executed ( very verbose?)

Tags: linux, zypper

I'm packaging my own rpm's, yet one of my rpm's is not doing what I expect, so I want to debug what zypper is doing: what lines of the `pre` and `post` part are executed and what are their outcomes... is there some kind of very verbose option for zypper? I tried:

```
zypper -vv in mypackage
```

but that doesn't give any extra information...

Comment: Why are you using `zypper`?? `rpm -Uvh mypackage.rpm` or verify the contents of the rpm before install with `rpm -qpl mypackage.rpm`.  `zypper` is just a wrapper that attempts to simplify some package management operations and extend functionality -- it doesn't replace, or add to, the basic `rpm` operations for `install, upgrade, query, etc.`

Answer (score 0):

This might give you way more then you need but could strace it.

```
strace -o /tmp/zypper.log zypper in mypackage
```